# ¿Existe alguna forma de manejar varios envíos de formularios al tiempo en Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Tengo un formulario de Google (como test) que ejecuta un *script* cada vez que ocurre un evento de *submit*. El script obtiene el correo del último participante que envió el formulario y envía un puntaje personalizado según las respuestas dadas al formulario.

```
function manager(e) {
   var ultimoCorreo = getUltimoCorreo();
   validarPuntaje(e.response, ultimoCorreo);
}

function getUltimoCorreo() {
   var rango = HOJA_CALCULO.getRange(1,2,HOJA_CALCULO.getLastRow(),1); // Rango donde se encuentran los correos en la hoja de calculo
   var ultimoCorreo = rango.getCell(HOJA_CALCULO.getLastRow(),1).getValue();
   return ultimoCorreo.toLowerCase(); // Convertimos el correo a minusculas por si el usuario mandó mal el correo
}
```

Pero estoy teniendo comportamientos extraños cuando el envío del formulario se realiza al mismo tiempo. Es decir, cuando 4 o 5 personas hacen *click* en el botón *Enviar*, se envían las puntuaciones al último correo registrado y no a cada uno.
Supongo que lo anterior ocurre porque tiene varios envíos a la vez y solo toma los datos del último envío.
¿Existe alguna forma de procesar un envío y, una vez termine con este, procesar el siguiente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí existe una forma, usa [el servicio "Lock"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/).

Del [artículo](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html) en inglés en el que se anuncia este servicio, adapté el siguiente ejemplo:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  // Queremos un candado público, uno que bloquee toda las invocaciones
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // espera 30 segundos antes de rendirse 
  // se obtuvo el candado, ahora podemos proceder 
  ...cualquier cosas que se acostumbre hacer aquí....
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: Hola Rubén, gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a leer el artículo, organizo el código, pruebo y vuelvo enseguida.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @Rubén, luego de pasar un buen rato intentándolo con la clase _LockService_ sin éxito, encontré esta respuesta en Stackoverflow que fue útil para mi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405355/google-form-on-submit-send-email-lock-doesnt-work . Sin embargo, dejaré marcada tu respuesta como la correcta porque, en efecto _LockService_ realiza lo que formulé en mi pregunta :)

Comment: Gracias por regresar @CarMoreno y compartirnos lo que finalmente te ayudó. Considera que puedes que puedes responder a tu propia pregunta para documentar la solución y compartirla con quienes tengan un situación similar en especial debido a que los comentarios deben ser usados  principalmente para solicitar que las preguntas o respuestas sean más claras y/o completas.