# ¿Evitar duplicidad de datos al agregar filas en una hoja de cálculo con google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un script asociado a un botón dentro de una hoja de calculo de google, lo único que hace es tomar la última fila de la Hoja2, la elimina y la agrega a la Hoja1. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
function agregarFila() {
  var libro=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var hoja1=libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1")
  var hoja2=libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 2")
  var ultimaFila=hoja2.getLastRow()
  hoja2.deleteRow(ultimaFila)
  var datos=hoja2.getRange(ultimaFila,1,1,hoja2.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  hoja1.appendRow(datos[0])  
}
```

El script funciona, pero me he topado con un problema, y es que si dos personas ejecutan el script al mismo tiempo el dato queda duplicado en la Hoja1. He intentado validar si el dato ya existe en la Hoja1 antes de agregarlo, pero al momento de ejecutar el script al mismo tiempo me sigue duplicando el dato en la Hoja1. El código completo con la validación es el siguiente:

```
function agregarFila() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var hoja1 = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1")
  var hoja2 = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 2")
  var ultimaFila = hoja2.getLastRow()
  var datos = hoja2.getRange(ultimaFila, 1, 1, hoja2.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  hoja2.deleteRow(ultimaFila)

  var yaExiste = existeDato(datos[0], hoja1)
  if (!yaExiste) {
    hoja1.appendRow(datos[0])
  }
}

function existeDato(dato, hoja) {
  var datosHoja1 = hoja.getRange(1, 1, hoja.getLastRow(), 1).getValues()
  var buscar = datosHoja1.find((el) => el[0] === dato[0])
  console.log(buscar)
  if (buscar) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar esto?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Existe alguna forma de manejar varios envíos de formularios al tiempo en Google Forms?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74754/existe-alguna-forma-de-manejar-varios-env%c3%ados-de-formularios-al-tiempo-en-google)

Comment: @Rubén creo que tu respuesta  es correcta pero está desactualizada, el método `getPublicLock()` ya no existe

Comment: Si bien `getPublicLock` fue reemplazado este sigue existiendo (al menos eso dice https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014#september_4_2014)

Comment: @Rubén ese link es del 2014. No sé cuando pero en algún momento esos métodos dejaron de estar disponibles. No aparecen en el autocompletado ni en la [referencia](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service)

Comment: Quiero colocar ese existeDato en este código, me pueden ayudar: function Guardar(){ var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("CONTACTO"); var datos = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("BASE DE DATOS"); const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); const sh = ss.getSheetByName("CONTACTO"); const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["D8","D10","D12","D14","D16","G8","G10","G12","G14","G16","K8","K10","K12","K14","K16","N8", "N10","N12","N14"]); rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => { if(r.isBlank()){ throw new Error(`${r.getA1Notation()} se encuentra vacía`)} }); var valores

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/370903)

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/370970)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un servicio llamado `LockService` que sirve para bloquear el script y garantizar nadie más pueda ejecutarlo hasta que termine su ejecución. Se usa de esta manera:

```
function agregarFila() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var hoja1 = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1")
  var hoja2 = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 2")
  // obtiene el lock (objeto necesario para bloquear el script)
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  // Si el script no está bloqueado, lo bloquea y avanza a la siguiente línea.
  // Caso contrario, espera hasta que se desbloquee o se agote el tiempo indicado (5 seg)
  lock.tryLock(5000);
  // valida que el script se haya desbloqueado
  if (lock.hasLock){
    var ultimaFila = hoja2.getLastRow()
    var datos = hoja2.getRange(ultimaFila, 1, 1, hoja2.getLastColumn()).getValues()
    hoja2.deleteRow(ultimaFila)
    var yaExiste = existeDato(datos[0], hoja1)
    if (!yaExiste) hoja1.appendRow(datos[0])
  }
  // desbloquea el script
  lock.releaseLock()
}
```

De esta forma se evitan los problemas de concurrencia. La función `existeDato()` podrías eliminarla ya que no debería haber datos duplicados. Aunque ahora tal vez debas cambiar la lógica porque las funciones pausadas podrían eliminar/agregar una fila que no era la deseada.

Comment: por alguna razón el lock no me funcionó dentro de la misma función agregarFila(), seguía teniendo el mismo comportamiento. Lo que hice fue crear una función auxiliar en la que obtengo el lock y luego llamo a agregarFila(), después libero el lock, y de esta manera si me funcionó.

Comment: Podrías escribir tu propia respuesta? Sería de ayuda para la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código que a mi me funcionó:

```
function agregarFila() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var hoja1 = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1")
  var hoja2 = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 2")
  var ultimaFila = hoja2.getLastRow()
  var datos = hoja2.getRange(ultimaFila, 1, 1, 
  hoja2.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  hoja2.deleteRow(ultimaFila)

  var yaExiste = existeDato(datos[0], hoja1)
  if (!yaExiste) {
    hoja1.appendRow(datos[0])
  }
}

function existeDato(dato, hoja) {
  var datosHoja1 = hoja.getRange(1, 1, hoja.getLastRow(), 1).getValues()
  var buscar = datosHoja1.find((el) => el[0] === dato[0])
  console.log(buscar)
  if (buscar) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function auxliar(){
 var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()

 lock.tryLock(5000);

 if(lock.hasLock){
  agregarFila()
 }

  
}
```